How to serialize object JSON with float field forcing trailing zeros (.NET + RemObjects)?
By using RemObjects and Oxygene over .NET, declaring a specific object type, I want to serialize it to JSON and maintain at least two decimal places after serialization.
Example:
MyType = private class
public
  valueD: System.Nullable<Double>;
end;

var 
  data: MyType;
  s: string;

begin

  data := new MyType;
  data.valueD := 1.9;

  s := new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);

  // Result:
  // s = {"valueD": 1.9}

  // I want this:
  // s = {"valueD": 1.90}

end;

How can I get result like "1.90"?

if you are using System.Text.Json, you will need to implement a custom converter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0#sample-basic-converter

Can you give a example? I think it's not applicable to solve my problem. Thanks!

Lee is correct in suggesting that you must implement a custom converter.
Here is an illustration:
uses
  Newtonsoft.Json;

type
  MyType = private class
  public
    valueD: nullable Double;
  end;

type
  MyTypeValueConverter = public class(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter<nullable Double>)
  public
    method ReadJson(reader: JsonReader; objectType: &Type; existingValue: nullable Double; hasExistingValue: Boolean; serializer: JsonSerializer): nullable Double; override;
    begin
      // NO-OP
    end;
    method WriteJson(writer: JsonWriter; value: nullable Double; serializer: JsonSerializer); override;
    begin
      writer.WriteValue("foo");
    end;
  end;
  
type
  Program = class
  public
    class method Main(args: array of String): Int32;
    begin
      var data  := new MyType;
      data.valueD := 1.9;
  
      var s := JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented, new MyTypeValueConverter());
  
      writeLn(s);
      
      // Result:
      // s = {"valueD": "foo"}
    end;
  end;
  
end.


From the use of System.Web.Script... you appear to be using .net Framework where-as I only have access to .net (on a Mac).  As a result, I have adapted the code to Newtonsoft.Json.  Newtonsoft supports both .net Framework and .net. You could switch to Newtonsoft or will have
to re-adapt the code for .net Framework.  The principle and mechanisms are the same, though the namespaces, required assemblies, and methods' signatures may change.

Additionally, I have modified the code to use Oxygene's nullable syntax, which simplifies the generics involved in the solution.
Since the crux of your problem is the custom serialization, I have not addressed the actual conversion to the number of decimal places; that is a mechanical exercise left for you.  Similarly, I have not addressed deserialization (reading values from JSON), though a NO-OP read method is required to override the abstract method in the converter base class.
Supplemental
The conversion you have in mind raises a potential complication...
You have specified "at least 2 decimal places"; this could lead to some unexpected results.
When a value cannot be precisely expressed in 2 decimal places (or less), you may end up with values being serialized with an unexpected number of additional decimal places and/or a loss of precision (values effectively being changed through serialization).
This may impact how you decide to implement your type and/or the serialization, though the mechanics of implementing a custom converter will remain the same (if still required).
